# delete session value on template

Tags: django, django-templates

i'm create a session value on a views(insertProduct):

```
def insertProduct
    request.session['insert_product'] = 'ok_insert'
    return redirect('list_products')

def listProducts
    context ={
     'productos':Products.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'mytemplate.html', context)
```

on my template validate if exist on session:

```
{% if request.session.insert_product == 'ok_insert'%}
 //do something
 //here i need delete the session value
{% endif %}
```

please maybe any idea or suggest thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For set is:

```
request.session['id_session'] = 'new value'
```

for get:

```
if 'id_session' in request.session:
    value = request.session['id_session']
```

more details in doc:
[session values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/sessions/)